# Comparison of unlike things - Being Logical

Tags: logic

I want a simple explanation of this statement from the book 'Being Logical': "No two things can be so unlike that they do not share the elemental act of existence. If, in comparing A and B, it is declared that B is "totally unlike" A, then there would be but one thing, A, since B would not exist"

Answer (score 1):

Compare with the [previous statement](https://books.google.it/books?id=xRCkNvDlRtYC&printsec=frontcover) (D.Q. McInerny, *Being Logical: A Guide to Good Thinking*, Random House, 2004 edition, page 57):

> Note this about the "completely alike" judgment: No two things can be so alike that they cease to be two things. If two things were to be identical in the literal sense, there would be but one thing.

Thus, "to be alike" must be assessed comparing the *properties* shared (or not) by the two things to be comapred. If they share absolutely **all** properties, including their spatio-temporal location, they will be absolutely indistinguishible, and thus identical, and thus "really one".

By contrast, two *existing* things have at least one common "property": *existence*. If not, one of them must be non existent, and thus not "a thing" at all.

Question: is *existence* a property, like color ?

See [Existence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/) as well as:

- Francesco Berto, [Existence as a Real Property: The Ontology of Meinongianism](https://books.google.it/books?id=UobUqRMyUawC&printsec=frontcover), Springer (2013).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at this is to say that we cannot compare two different things unless they are the same thing in some respect. For a start, they must both be 'things'. Difference is impossible without identity and identity is impossible without difference. This may be what internet-entity was getting at in his/her answer. 'The opposite of a thing is contained within the thing'.

The two things to be compared much belong in the same category or they cannot be compared. So for two things to be different in some respects they must be the same in others. If both have the property or condition of existence then this would be enough to allow a comparison.